# Quiz in Typescript-triggering events doesnt work properly

Tags: javascript, typescript, dom

I have several questions about my code as i dont know why it isnt working properly.
first of all if i click one of the buttons or even the textarea where the question is displayed it triggers all buttons and moves to next question without me clicking nextQuestion button.
Next if click through all questions and my counter variable hs the same value as my questions length i get the error variable counter undefined.
and my last question is can i get a number id if i click on the buttons to compare it with the id in my questions array?

```js
class Quiz {
    public questions=[{question},{answers[4]},{id:number}//pseudo code
    public qst=<HTMLElement> document.querySelector(".message-content");
    public answer=<HTMLElement> document.querySelector("answer");
    public aButtons=<HTMLElement> document.getElementById("btns");
    public nextQ=<HTMLElement> document.getElementById("nextQuestion");
    public counter:number=0;

    constructor(){
        addEventListener("click",this.buttonListener);
    }

    public buttonListener=(e)=>{
        let quest=this.qst.textContent=this.questions[this.counter].question;    
        let a=(<HTMLInputElement>this.aButtons.getElementsByClassName("btn")[0]).innerHTML=this.questions[this.counter].answers[0];
        let b=(<HTMLInputElement>this.aButtons.getElementsByClassName("btn")[1]).innerHTML=this.questions[this.counter].answers[1];
        let c=(<HTMLInputElement>this.aButtons.getElementsByClassName("btn")[2]).innerHTML=this.questions[this.counter].answers[2];
        let d=(<HTMLInputElement>this.aButtons.getElementsByClassName("btn")[3]).innerHTML=this.questions[this.counter].answers[3];
        console.log(e.target.id+" "+e.currentTarget);

        if(e.target.id="nextQuestion"){
            this.counter+=1
        } else if(this.counter>=this.questions.length){
            this.counter=0;
        }

    }    

}
    
new Quiz();
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row max-height align-items-center">
        <div class="col-10 mx-auto col-md-8 message-container text-center p-3">
            <h4 class="text-capitalize">MyQuiz</h4>
            <br>
            <h4 class="message-content text-uppercase">Area for Questions</h4>
            <br><br>
            <div class="col-11" id="btns">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success" id="btn1">Button 111111</button>
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success" id="btn2">Button 211111</button>
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success" id="btn3">Button 311111</button>
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success" id="btn4">Button 222224</button>
            </div>   

           <br><br>
           <h4 class="answer text-uppercase">correct/false Answer</h4>

           <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="nextQuestion">next Question</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: **TL;DR** you really need to include a more abstract version of your code.

Comment: @EternalDarkness its just one method and relevant variables. i edited the questions array. .and the html part is also abstracted

Answer (score 0):

In your constructor:

```
addEventListener("click", this.buttonListener);
```

...won't work because `addEventListener` is a method for DOM elements, and you're just calling it directly. But assuming you change to something like:

```
document.querySelector('#nextQuestion').addEventListener("click", this.buttonListener);
```

...this still won't work. The reason why is in the way that JavaScript calls functions. The function reference `this.buttonListener`, when called, will not automatically be invoked such where `this` is set to your `Quiz` instance. Therefore, when this expression is evaluated in that function

```
this.counter
```

...`this.counter` will be undefined. You can work around this by using [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind):

```
document
  .querySelector('#nextQuestion')
  .addEventListener("click", this.buttonListener.bind(this);
```

This will make it so that no matter how `this.buttonListener` is called, `this` will be set to your `Quiz` instance.